# Get OAuth access token for using AT&T speech api

Tags: iphone, ios6, speech-to-text

I am using AT&T Speech API for converting speech to text in my iphone app.Where i need to convert audio into text.
My question is: how to get OAuth access token? As i need it for API call.

Comment: Do you mean you don't understand how to use OAuth or you don't understand something specific to the AT&T API? Do you have a valid account?

Comment: I have App Key and App Secret. Using these parameters how can i obtain OAuth access token

Comment: I strongly recommend you use an OAuth library as it involves sending messages, getting responses, checking hashes, etc... Implementing it yourself will likely result in a buggy implementation. [Have a look here for some suggestions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838618/which-oauth-library-do-you-find-works-best-for-objective-c-iphone)

Comment: Thank you Basic for your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

[image: Manage My Account]

- Sign in to your ATT Developer account and click on "Manage My Account"

[image: sandbox]

- Create a new app or enter into the sandbox of your existing application

[image: appkey and appsecret]

- The App Key and App Secret are used for your OAuth token

[image: oauth token]